# isEnabled() failed to find element

Tags: selenium, isenabled

I am new to selenium. I trying to check whether button is enable or not through isEnabled(). But when I am running this program it generating a error as "Unable to locate element" of button.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class test 
{
static WebDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\rakesh\\software\\selenium browser\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://app.crossover.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,5500)", "");

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Available Jobs")).click();

    Boolean search_btn_ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='available-jobs']/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/button")).isEnabled();

    if(search_btn_ele.FALSE)
    {
        System.out.println("Button is disable before giving search keys");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Button is enable before giving search keys");
    }

    WebElement search_txtfield_ele= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='available-jobs']/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/input"));
    search_txtfield_ele.sendKeys("Chief");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WebDriverWait to wait for the element to be present:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible((By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drp85"))));
```

Comment: thank you @Anton. I resolved my question by                                       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(expression)))

Comment: Glad, I could help. Can you mark the question as answered?